# Program ran from subprocess.run() in python3, cannot create files

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I have a program that is supposed to create a text file. When called from subprocess.run() in python3, the program runs but it does not create the text file. The program works as expected when called from the terminal.

```
import subprocess as subp
...
comm=[os.getcwd()+'/test/myprogram.bin','arg1','arg2']
compl_proc = subp.run(comm,
                      capture_output=True,
                      text=True,
                      check=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The file was in the python script directory, because I never told `subprocess.run()` what is the current working directory of the subprocess. So `cwd='...'` is added.

```
import subprocess as subp
import os
...
comm=[os.getcwd()+'/test/myprogram.bin','arg1','arg2']
compl_proc = subp.run(comm,
                      cwd=os.getcwd()+'/test/',
                      capture_output=True,
                      text=True,
                      check=True)
```